# Lumen problems with redirect and middlewares

Tags: laravel, lumen

I try to use Lumen for my project but I have two problem, first when I try to make `return redirect()->back();` from my controller action method I get back status code 500 to the page. There is nothing in the log file and I don't see any error message on the page (I uncommented dot files and facades in the bootstrap/app.php file and in my .env file I set environment to local and debug to true).

The same problem I have when I uncomment some middlewares in the bootstrap/app.php file.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the Laravel log files **and** the ones from your server?

Comment: I see only lumen.log file and it is empty. There is also nothing in my apache log files.

Answer (score 0):

I think redirect()->back() needs session to work so I first had to enable the middlewares in the bootstrap/app.php file but it will work only if I add SESSION_DRIVE to the .env file (dot files must also be enabled in the app.php file).